# Can you explain why doesn't current always go through the first part of a parallel circuit (without water or heavy math)?

Tags: parallel, basic

I have tried to understand this over and over.  I don't understand how current ever makes it beyond one branch of a parallel circuit.  I apologize for the circuit if it doesn't make sense.

I simply do not understand how anything ever gets past R1.  I've read about water until I'm blue in the face, and I've seen lots of math.

When I close the circuit, how does it get to R2, R3, and so on.  I don't think current is going in a line like water analogies make out.

When the circuit is closed, does the whole circuit "somehow" have "power"?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f18Jlx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Circuit schematics do not imply order or distance, just connectivity, so all three resistors are equally close to the source and current does not pass one to reach the others.

Comment: Do you have a link for that, so I can understand it?

Comment: Your circuit applies 1V to the wires. The wires have 1V. Wires go to each resistor. Each resistor has 1V over it. Same as all lamps or electrical appliances or mains sockets have 110V or 220V or whatever your country has, and each load is independently plugged into this voltage. What is the problem of underatanding it, what kind of answer would explain it to you?

Comment: For something like this I would get a textbook which would explain schematics in a logical sequence rather than try and piece it all together yourself.

Comment: @learntofix Analogies help for certain cases. But you will need to understand, at some point, that subatomic particles don't behave like macroscale substances like water. You will need to let go of what you can put your hands on and feel. And move your mind, elsewhere. But let's take a macroscale case of a compressor tank with hoses. You have three separate attachments that allow you to fill a tire. If you get three people to start filling all three tires at once, then it works fine. It doesn't only fill the first tire. Because the pressure is everywhere the same throughout the line.

Comment: @learntofix But closer towards reality you need to understand that electric repulsion is a trillion-trillion-trillion-trillion-trillion times stronger than gravity. Even the slightest imbalance is unacceptable to nature. It is unimaginable just how powerful electric forces are. We cannot get our minds around it. So when a voltage source is applied, the electrons almost immediately arrange themselves on all the surfaces along all the conductors so as to guide the motion of current in the wires. There's a `gradient` that impels current. And it is `powerful`. No room for any slack in this system!

Comment: @Justme if the current starts at the beginning and it hits the first branch, why does the current keep going and hit the other two branches?

Comment: @periblepsis I will hae to read on electric repulsion.  Flow eludes me.

Comment: Current does *not* just keep going: it *splits*. Voltage keeps "going", think of *at the speed of light*.

Comment: @learntofix In one sense you are still thinking in terms of wiring, as though things have to first flow along a wire to get to the first resistor. But the gradients that are quickly set up on the wire surfaces -- it happens so fast you almost cannot grasp it --guide the current both to and then past resistors along the wiring (if you must think in terms of how wires are wired -- which you should break yourself of.) This process works so perfectly that we instead choose to simply consider the entire wire as a single lumped thing. Not a physical thing. But a virtual reality thing.

Comment: @periblepsis Do you mean the whole circuit lights up at once, regardless?

Comment: @learntofix Because current does not do that. I already said all resistors have 1V over them, so all resistors have 10mA through them, and Kirchhoff's current and voltage laws say that there is a sum of 30mA out of the supply and current splits up.

Comment: @learntofix Copper is a veritable ocean of electrons. Just \$1\:\text{cc}\$ of copper has \$\frac{N_A\,\cdot\, \rho_{_\text{Cu}}}{m_{_\text{Cu}}}\approx 8.49\times 10^{22}\,\frac{\text{atoms}}{\text{cc}}\$ and about the same number of free electrons. Suppose a 20-gauge copper wire, diameter 32 mils. The drift velocity for \$1\:\text{A}\$ is \$\frac{1\:\text{A}}{1.3476\times 10^{4}\:\frac{\text{Coulomb}}{\text{cc}}\:\cdot\: 0.51887\: \text{mm}^2}\approx 143 \:\frac{\mu m}{s}\$. That's a little more than a tenth of a mm per second. Not a large velocity. But starting is nearly instantaneous.

Comment: @learntofix The reason a current doesn't require much speed is because there are just so many electrons -- copper is dense beyond your imagination with them. They repel each other, of course. Which is why there are a few more on the surface than in the interior (those on the surface don't have to deal with repulsion from the air, just the interior, so more pack up near the surface.) However, when you apply a battery, charges do re-arrange themselves ***very quickly*** at the start. That's because nearby electrons here will affect those very far away and very quickly without needing to move.

Comment: @learntofix I think you might be well-served by finding a good book on physics. I can definitely recommend Matter & Interactions by Chabay and Sherwood (latest edition would be better value.) It doesn't swamp you in mysterious equations with poor explanations. Instead it provides a clear exposition and you can skip over most of the math and just from the text alone understand a great deal. It's not written for super-genius types. It is really written for DIY types -- hobbyists -- yet it doesn't lead you astray with false analogies, either. You get the real scoop.

Comment: voltage at a node is like the pressure on the skin of a balloon ... the pressure rises everywhere at the same time ... there is no isolated location that receives all of the pressure, and elsewhere that does not receive pressure ... it is voltage that pushes current through a resistor ... if there is a voltage difference between the two ends of a resistor  then current will be pushed through it

Comment: The sum of all currents (in and out) on a junction is 0.  Kirchhoff's Current Law.  A junction or dot on a circuit allows more than one path for current.  The amount of current depends upon circuit components.  Current splits or recombines at the dots.

Comment: The water analogy is a very useful tool for understanding the very basic fundamentals of electric circuits. If there are three houses on the same street, and a person in the first house turns on a faucet, do you understand why it's still possible for people in the other two houses to get water from their faucets at the same time? If you do, then you're halfway to having a basic understanding of how the circuit with the three resistors works. The other half is to learn which water concepts correspond to which electrical concepts.

Answer (score 2):

Kirchoff's Voltage Law says that the sum of voltages around a closed path is zero.  (This is one form that expresses the conservation of energy over a closed path.  Since voltage is just energy per unit charge, the sum of voltages around a closed path must be zero:  you can't get a net change in energy per unit charge—voltage—just by going around such a path.  If you could, you would also allow for perpetual motion.)

You have several closed paths in your schematic.  Of interest are the paths including \$V_1\$ and \$R_1\$, \$V_1\$ and \$R_2\$, and \$V_1\$ and \$R_3\$.  Since all three resistors are equal, each such loop can be treated identically, but they nonetheless all are distinct from one another.  In all three cases, the voltage drop across the resistor must match the voltage rise across the voltage source, implying that all three resistors are subject to an identical voltage, 1 V.  Thus all conduct identical current:
\begin{align*}
   i_{R_1} &= i_{R_2} = i_{R_3} = \frac{V_1}{R_1} = \frac{V_1}{R_2} = \frac{V_1}{R_3} \\
           &= \frac{1\,\text{V}}{100\,\Omega} \\
           &= 10\,\text{mA}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

> When the circuit is closed, does the whole circuit "somehow" have "power"?

Yes.  Your drawing shows the answer.

There is zero resistance between V1 and R1, R1 and R2, and R2 and R3.  Therefore, there is nothing limiting the movement of energy all the way across the top (and bottom) of your circuit.  That energy moves at the speed of light in copper (which is slower than the speed of light in a vacuum, but still really fast).

Therefore, all of the energy out of V1 is available equally to all three resistors.  Each resistor resists (!) the movement of electrons through it, so the current for each resistor depends on its resistance value, per Ohm's Law.  Don't panic; it's grade school arithmetic.  I understand your frustration with the water analogy, but it does apply.  Your circuit is like a bucket with three holes in the bottom.  As long as there is way more water in the bucket than the holes can drain rapidly, the water through each hole is proportional to the size of the hole.

If the total current through all three resistors is less than the current available from V1, then that's it.  The voltage value of V1 appears across each resistor identically, each resistor draws whatever current it needs, and the system is stable.  If the total current for the resistors is greater than that available, then the value of V1 will decrease until the total current is within its capability, or the supply will blow a fuse, or something else depending on what V1 actually is in the real world.

A final thought.  Resistors are called that because they do in fact resist the flow of electrons.  If you replaced R1 with a piece of wire, then your initial hypothesis would be correct - all of the current would go through W1 (now a resistor with 0 ohms) and none would bet to R2 or R3.

The current is distributed proportionally based on the resistance values.  That is the single most basic fact in all of electrical engineering.  There are almost perfect parallels in mechanical engineering, thermodynamics, fluid mechanics, aerodynamics, astrophysics, etc.  It's all force, mass, and movement.

Comment: It won't let me vote up.  Thanks.  I read what you said, but I thought that as soon as it hit that first branch, it wouldn't try to keep going to the other branches.  For example, what if there were just three wires there, no resistors.  Would the power go only through that first branch?  Or what if there were no resistor at R1 and there are at R2 & R3, what happens?

Comment: @learntofix If there were no resistors, and just 3 wire loops, we would have to discuss a *far* more complicated model than you are learning right now.  In reality, every wire has some resistance.  No wires is perfect, none of them.  However, measuring those really small resistances gets tricky, and it doesn't always follow your pretty diagrams.  For example, the wire path that goes throguh R1 (which was replaced by more wire) is shorter, so it *could* have a lower resistance than the path through R2 (also replaced).  Howeer, its also possible for imperfections in the R1 wire to make...

Comment: ... it actually have a higher resistance than the R2 (replaced) path.  The physics of this are *well* beyond the level your teachers are teaching you now, but they do build on top of the things you're learning now about parallel resistences.  So recognize taht they are teaching you an *idealized* model, called the Lumped Element model, which is imperfect.  However, for "well behaved circuits," like the one you started with, they are accurate enough.  You might be off by 0.0001% due to the resistance of wires, but you'll find the errors on your measured resistances have a larger effect

Comment: The first sentence of the last paragraph covers this.  Bare wires have resistance.  Up to the max current capability of the energy source, the current will distribute proportional to the resistances, no mater how large or small.

Comment: @AnalogKid, **inversely proportional**...

Answer (score 0):

You have by yourself said that everyone of the three resistors in your schematic will have current 0,01 amperes. And the current starts as soon as you put the circuit together.

How did you say it?

Answer: You have connected one volt between the ends of each resistor and you have told that every resistor will have current one volt divided by 100 ohms; thats 0,01 amperes.

How did you say that it's just one volt divided by 100 ohms? You did it by saying that the resistors are 100 ohms and the voltage is one volt. By using ohms you imply all what the concept ohm means.

The current starts as soon as you put the circuit together. That's because you have drawn plain wires and inserted no parts which causes delay. If there were some transmission line or capacitors the situation would be different. But you have very cleanly with your drawing told that there's no parts which cause some delay. A wire in a schematic has no such property as length. It only tells which is connected to what. In that sense all of your resistors have exactly the same relatonship to the voltage source: Connected in parallel and the connection causes nothing else but there's a connection, a lossless and delayless way for current.

In theory you could say: "I only drew them as 100 ohm resistors, but I have still not revealed what they really are and how long delays MY wires cause!" Don't do it! Your question and maybe also your account would be closed quite soon.